# XPATH - How to pick up a div class using an OR statement?

Tags: xpath

I am using XPATH to grab info from html webpages. Sometimes the URL will change slightly on some of the pages BUT the 'new URL' I need will appear on the old URL in a div with a certain class.

So what I need to do is have an XPATH query that looks for this div and returns the contents of it - the href - OR just return the old URL.

How do I write a query for this?

For example:

```
<div class='old-url'>www.example.com/old-url</div>

<div class='new-url'>www.example.com/new-url</div>
```

So I want to basically say 'return the old one UNLESS you see the new one there, if that is the case, return the new one.

Here's a sample:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml" xmlns:og="http://opengraphprotocol.org/schema/">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en" href="http://www.example.com"/>

<div id="" class="pgLinks">
<a href="/example-text" class="guiArw sprite-pagePrev ">&laquo;</a>
<a href="/example-text-2" class="paging taLnk ">1</a>
<span class="paging pageDisplay">2</span>
```

Comment: For future questions please make sure to: Check the formatting (the HTML was parsed instead printed) and to include what you tried. Posting _valid_ markup and code is also something regarded good etiquette, broken markup/code and formatting always shows lack of effort when posting questions and will reduce chance of good answers. Did you have a look at the [FAQ]?

Comment: Sorry @jens, I didn't realise it was incorrect. Will be more careful.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have this xml(as part of your html):

```
<div>
  <div class='new-url'>www.example.comnew-url</div>
  <div class='old-url'>www.example.comold-url</div>
</div>
```

Idea is to select both, but old-url only if count of new-url elements is 0:

`/div/div[@class='new-url' or (@class='old-url' and count(./../div[@class='new-url'])=0)]`